# В чем разница между сокетами блокируемыми/неблокируемыми и синхронными/асинхронными?

Tags: windows, c, сокет, c++, linux

В чем разница между сокетами блокируемыми/неблокируемыми и синхронными/асинхронными?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Сокеты бывают блокирующие и неблокирующие. Суть в том, что в случае блокирующих сокетов при попытке прочитать (и записать) данные функция чтения будет ждать до тех пор, пока не прочитает хотя бы один байт или произойдет разрыв соединения или придет сигнал. В случае неблокирующих сокетов функция чтения проверяет, есть ли данные в буфере, и если есть - сразу возвращает, если нет, то она не ждет и также сразу возвращает, что прочитано 0 байт.

А вот синхронные/асинхронные сокеты - это изобретение Майкрософта. Дело в том, что когда вышла 3.11 виндовс, то в ней была только *кооперативная* многозадачность (это когда само приложение решало, что оно уже поработало и пора дать другим поработать. Если приложение зависло, то остальные приложения курят в сторонке). Неблокирующие сокеты были бы решением, но с ними есть одна проблема - в винде есть цикл выборки сообщений, и эти два цикла сложно было согласовать. Треды (потоки) тогда было что-то заоблачное, поэтому блокирующие сокеты также не были решением. Поэтому Майкрософт сделала асинхронные сокеты. Достаточно было зарегистрировать сокет, и если по нему приходили данные, то система посылала обычное сообщение через цикл обработки сообщений вместе с данными. А его уже было легко обработать.
Это, конечно, смешало мухи с котлетами (точнее gui с сетевой частью), но сильно упростило разработку сетевых приложений. Но более-менее сложную логику оно конечно же усложнило.

Comment: Считаю данный ответ исчерпывающим. :)

Comment: @KoVadim, да да Вы правы. Просто похоливорить захотелось. Забылся, что не в ИРКе

Comment: С виндовыми не знаком, но

всегда считал, что в \*nix (по крайней мере BSD и Linux) асинхронный сокет, это тот, который генерит сигналы SIGIO и SIGURG, если его status flags содержат `O_ASYNC` и он доступен для неблокируемого чтения (или записи).

Подробнее см. `man fcntl`. 

--

Сделать сокет (и вообще файловый дескриптор)  можно асинхронным так:

   void hsig (int s) { ... }
   ...
   signal(SIGIO, hsig);
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_ASYNC);
   fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());

Проще всего поиграться с `fd = 0`

(только запускать лучше: `cat | ./a.out`).