# Написать программу ping, с помощью сырых сокетов с++

Tags: c++, сокет, tcp-ip, tracert, icmp

**Написать программу ping, с помощью сырых сокетов с++**

Я вообще без понятия как это делать, читал уже про сокеты, протоколы TCP/IP, UDP/IP, но и то только про блокирующие(про асинхронные наверное не судьба почитать), информация в интернете есть, но и в тоже время ее нет (чего стоят статьи на геймдеве 2003г кол-во 4шт, про ICMP ни слова)

Так вот в этой программе должны использоваться сырые сокеты (RAW SOCKETS)

Внимание, знатоки, вопрос: Где и что почитать, чтобы суметь реализовать то что я написал выше?

Answer (score 4):

На **codeproject** есть [пример](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23793/Ping-and-Traceroute) такой программы. Это кстати первая ссылка при гуглении "c++ traceroute".

Comment: странно вижу эту статью впервые, что посоветуете еще почитать интересуют асинхронные сокеты и многопоточность

Comment: [Тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/371655/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD) оказывается уже был вопрос про синхронные/асинхронные и блокирующие/не блокирующие сокеты

Comment: Для реализации данной задачи в примере использовались синхронные неблокирующие сокеты. Но если надо для чего-то использовать именно асинхроные сокеты, я бы сразу смотрел в сторону **boost::asio**. Конкретных книжек или статей не посоветую, я обычно смотрю примеры реализации.